# Save in Django Admin sometimes fails

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a portfolio page with django, and i'm noticing a strange behaviour when a try to save an edited entry. It saves, and then it seems that the redirect fails to catch the ID and then goes to a 404 page that says `domain.com/admi/internal_error.html/` in the URL (note the `admi`, sometimes is `ad` or `adm`). It happens with both 'Save' and 'Save and continue editing'.

This is my model

```
from django.db import models
from ramonlapenta.portfolio.managers import EntryManager
from ramonlapenta.slughifi import slughifi

class Type(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.type

class Entry(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    description = models.TextField()
    requirement = models.TextField()
    solution = models.TextField()
    url = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64)
    published = models.BooleanField(db_index=True, default=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="logos")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="portfolio", height_field='height', width_field='width')
    height = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    objects = EntryManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s - %s" % (self.title, self.created) 

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "entries"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slughifi(self.title)
        super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And this is the admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from ramonlapenta.portfolio.models import Type
from ramonlapenta.portfolio.models import Entry
from django import forms

class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('Title', {'fields' : ['title']}),
        ('Address', {'fields' : ['url']}),
        ('Description', {'fields' : ['description','requirement','solution']}),
        ('Type', {'fields' : ['type']}),
        ('Image', {'fields' : ['logo', 'image']}),
    ]
    list_display = ('title', 'created')
    list_filter = ['created', 'type']

admin.site.register(Type)
admin.site.register(Entry, EntryAdmin)
```

This is my entry manager, where i only filter the results.

```
from django.db import models

class EntryManager(models.Manager):
    def published(self):
        return self.model.objects.filter(published=True).order_by('-id')
```

This is the general urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^', include('site.pages.urls')),
    (r'^', include('site.blog.urls')),
    (r'^', include('site.portfolio.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

And the portfolio urls.py

from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

```
urlpatterns = patterns('ramonlapenta.portfolio.views',
    url(r'^portfolio/$', 'index', name="port-main"),
    url(r'^portfolio/(?P<item_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$', 'detail', name="port-slug"),
    url(r'^portfolio/type/(?P<type>[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$', 'type', name="port-type")
)
```

Thos is what i see with HttpFox:
[image]

Note: everything else works fine, even there it sometimes works fine, and the public site works fine too. The problem is just editing a portfolio entry.

Does anybody knows why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Comment: Nope, i tried using slugify from django and the problem is still there :(

Comment: What is this custom manager doing? Would suggest switching to a regular manager for a moment and then testing for errors.

Comment: I'm almost sure that the problem is outside Django (those `internal_error.html` and `admi`...). Does this thing happen if you use Django's development server? If it doesn't (or you can't really check), then I guess you should look at your production server's logs and see what's happening at the moment when you save an entry. If it does happen with development server as well, then I'd suggest to check that you're using latest stable Django version.

Comment: Not too sure, but what version of django are you using? Make sure your django admin templates are in sync with the rest of Admin app.

Comment: Dreamhost / Django 1.2 i'll try to make some tests with this information and get back here.

Comment: Ok, tested with development server (Django 1.3), no errors, works like a charm.But  I don't think I'm up to try to change Dreamhost's version of Django. @mohi666 I'm not sure what you mean with "in sync"

Comment: By "in sync" I meant your admin templates and your Django have the same version. I personally use a customized template in my projects. Sometimes when I upgrade django, some of the minor functionality don't work as expected in admin, because of my old version of admin templates.

Comment: Then yes, they are in sync, i haven't touched the admin files.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the main `url.py` is catching some of the admin data (being that any admin action will be considered by all the other urlconfs.

Try to put the admin urls at the top:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^', include('site.pages.urls')),
    (r'^', include('site.blog.urls')),
    (r'^', include('site.portfolio.urls')),
)
```

**Edit: second guess**

The key information is that second 302 in the request list. Someone (probably dreamost's apache) is eating the response and returning a redirect to a custom page.

In this case setting `DEBUG = True` is of no help, because the response would have anyway the same error.

This means two things:

1. You have an error somewhere in your Model's code, probably some attribute/field/property that's used to display the object.

   To isolate the error, try to find a pattern on which specific values trigger the error and which values allows to load the admin form.
2. You can't see the django error page unless you either work locally in the development server (`manage.py runserver`) or disable custom error pages in dreamhost as other suggest.

Comment: I did that just now, still no luck, see the attached image.

Comment: Try to reproduce the bug locally (if you can) using only the development server (`manage.py runserver`), you should avoid that nasty dreamhost redirect, and see why there is a 500 error raised.

Comment: @saverio, seems like the bug is not reproducible with development server (see comments on the question), perhaps something's wrong with the production server setup.

Comment: @anton-strogonoff With development server I meant to run `runserver` with the correct django version (1.2). Not to run the "development version" of django, or any other version (1.3), like said in the comment.

Comment: Ok, i'll change my local version for 1.2 ans try that.

Comment: I could not reproduce the error in my local development server with 1.3 or 1.2, I'm trying to check the log files to see what i can find.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing your setup and what appears in server logs at the time you're saving an entry might help us locate a problem. It's likely that the cause is outside Django (since the bug is not reproducible under Django's development server).

Anyway, you might find some of these solutions relevant:

- [Django on dreamhost problem](http://grimboy.co.uk/blawg/django-on-dreamhost-problem/) (old post, but symptoms described there are similar, might be relevant if you're running Django on FastCGI).
- [getting 500 internal server error with django on dreamhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978551/getting-500-internal-server-error-with-django-on-dreamhost) (in short: just try re-create the whole setup and see if that helps).
- Or you may want simply to google `dreamhost django 500` in case you haven't already, seems like  people frequently encounter similar problem while setting up Django on Dreamhost.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be curious to see your urls.py . My guess is that the regex for the admin site is bogus.

Comment: There's the urls.py files too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For sure an error is happening when you save those entries and you should check your logs. Or try reproduce it with DEBUG=True

My guess is that you are using dreamhost and Dreamhost allows you to define custom error pages and "internal_error.html" is for the status 500 error page (see : http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Creating_custom_error_pages).

Comment: Indeed it's Dreamhost, and Django 1.2. I'll check this too.

Comment: I set the debug true, and i still get a 404, not a 500. I'll try to check log files and see what they say.

Comment: The 404 is for the non-existing `internal_error.html` page, probably dreamhost's catches the 500 ERROR response and converts it into a 302 REDIRECT to the error page. Disable any dreamhost's specific redirection to be able to set up your own error pages in Django (or see the default ones).

Comment: I see the 500 error when I mess up code somewhere else, but not here :S.

Comment: As saverio was saying, try turning the dreamhost magic off with a .htacess modification as indicated in the [http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Creating_custom_error_pages](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Creating_custom_error_pages) and see the standard apache error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to have a look at your dreamhost `error.log` file.

The sure thing is that the problem comes from your dreamhost configuration and not your django code (since it is working properly in development with Django 1.2)